# How to use google translator in react app so that i can translate whole site?

Tags: reactjs, google-translate

im going to translate the whole site in different language,and the site has codeed by react,how should it works?
maybe you have other language translate for me to change the whole site in different language?

Comment: Hi Maris, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid that this question is likely to be closed because it is very broad and will get "opinion-based" answers. It's best to be quite specific about what you need, what you've tried and what the problem is. I'll leave an answer for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up translations for all of your strings. I use [i18Next](
https://www.i18next.com/).

In each of your react components you change any string `<a onClick={something}>Take action</a>` to `<a onClick={something}>{translationFor('Take action')}</a>`.

[React-18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) lets you do this easily.

Comment: This is the internationalization part, and I would also recommend a mature library like i18next.
But for the localization part you need something like https://locize.com